# How do I check a cookie using MVC 4 and the "Remember Me" function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, remember-me

I created a new MVC 4 web application using the newer SimpleMembership model.  The "out of the box" site creation by VS2012 creates the Account Controller and a "Remember Me" checkbox on the log in page.  But when I check this box, it's not remembering me.

I am new to certain parts of MVC, but it appears that there is nothing in my AccountController at the Login area that checks for the cookie that was previously saved.  Do I need to write code for that? I did find an example of that on another site, but before I implement that I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

It just seems strange to me that Microsoft would automate the Remember Me function as part of a new MVC 4 web application, but not include that part of the code.

For saving the cookie, I'm using the following that I found on this site:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
int timeout = model.RememberMe ? 525600 : 30; // Timeout in minutes, 525600 = 365 days.
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(model.UserName, model.RememberMe, timeout);
string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(52000);//  timeout
cookie.HttpOnly = true; // cookie not available in javascript.
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);`
```

Comment: WebSecurity (in MVC4) already has the “Remember Me” function. See WebSecurity.Login

Comment: As LostInComputer said, the method WebSecurity.Login [already allows cookie persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). The third parameter is named `persistCookie` and does just that. The default AccountController passes as that parameter the value of the `RememberMe` property in the LogInModel.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured this out.  It wasn't actually the "remember me" that was failing.  It was the fact that I assign session variables at login, and those were expiring.  I increased the session time, but I also wrote some additional code in crucial places to re-establish those variables as needed.  And now it appears to be working.

I was just confused because I didn't see any code in the Account Controller that looked for the cookie and then re-logged in the person.  From the comments above, I assume that is inherent in WebSecurity